# Help simplifying trig equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am having trouble understanding how the following equation is reduced to a simpler one.

$$y = \frac{A}{\cos(a)}.(\cos(a)\sin(ax) - \sin(a)\cos(ax))$$

This simplifies to

$$y = \frac{A}{\cos(a)}.\sin a(x-1) $$

Could someone explain how this works ?

Thank you

Comment: because $$\sin(p-q)=\sin p\cos q-\cos p\sin q$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Euler's identity, we have
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
Hence substituting $\theta$ as $(a-b)$, we get
$$e^{i(a-b)}=\cos(a-b)+i\sin(a-b)$$
But the LHS can also be written as the following
$$\begin{align}e^{i(a-b)}&=\frac{e^{ia}}{e^{ib}}\\
&=\frac{\cos a+i\sin a}{\cos b+i\sin b}\\
&=\frac{\cos a+i\sin a}{\cos b+i\sin b}\cdot\frac{\cos b-i\sin b}{\cos b-i\sin b}\\
&=\frac{(\cos a+i\cos a) \cdot (\cos b+i\sin b)}{\cos^2 b+\sin^2 b}\\
&=(\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b)+i(\cos a\sin b-\cos b\sin a)
\end{align}$$
Comparing the like terms from the two results gives the required expansion of $\sin(a-b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Angle sum formula for sines:

$\sin (a+b)=\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b$

Can be converted to a difference formula:

$\begin{align} \sin(a-b) &= \sin a \cos (-b)+ \cos a \sin (-b) \\ &= \color{blue}{\boxed{\color{red}{\sin a \cos b - \cos a \sin b}}} \end{align}$